# Can I replicate inheritance with overloading?

Tags: c++

**Prelude:** I have updated this question to address NicolBolas' suggestion. Please leave a constructive comment if you downvote, thank you.

I'm writing a function that takes a number (`uint`) or a flag that it's not a number. It then goes on to work with the given number or `-1`.

Here's the idea

```
struct Numeric {
    virtual int to_int() const = 0;
};
struct NotANumber : Numeric {
    int to_int () const {
        return -1;
    }
}
struct Number : Numeric {
    const uint n;
    Number (const uint n): n(n) {}
    int to_int () const {
        return n;
    }
};
```

So then my function could be used as:

```
calculate_stuff(NotANumber());
calculate_stuff(Number(4));
```

My question is whether it's possible to move the `to_int` method outside of the classes, into the form of an overloaded function:

```
struct Numeric {};

struct NotANumber : Numeric {}

struct Number : Numeric {
    const uint n;
    Number (const uint n): n(n) {}
};

int Numeric_to_int (const NotANumber) {
    return -1;
}

int Numeric_to_int (const Number n) {
    return n.n;
}
```

This doesn't seem to work. Is it possible to fix this? Is the issue that overloading happens at compile time, whereas overriding is at runtime?

(I think I'm going to use `std::optional` and `value_or` for this specific problem, but I would still like to know the answer to my questions above)

**Edit:** sorry, I should've clarified what "doesn't work" means:

```
int calculate_stuff (const Numeric n) {
    std::cout << Numeric_to_int(n) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't compile: `no matching function for call to ‘Numeric_to_int(const Numeric&)’`

Comment: "*This doesn't seem to work.*" *What* doesn't work? Where is there an error? How does it fail?

Comment: returning -1 doesn't look like a good idea unless you want to treat all negative numbers or at least -1 as non a number.

Comment: @NicolBolas: thanks, I've updated my question

Comment: @NathanOliver: yeah, sorry, this is a poorly named toy example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> int calculate_stuff (const Numeric n)
> ```

How could it work? You passed in a base class. *By value*. The compiler cannot know what derived class it used to be. In fact, since you took the base class by value, the compiler *knows* that `n` is *neither* of the derived classes.

C++ isn't Java; if you pass something by value, you make a copy (or move to it). And if you passed one of the derived classes, that [causes *slicing*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing); you only copy the base class data. The parameter is therefore exactly what it says: an object who's dynamic type is `Numeric`. Exactly and only that, not one of its derived classes.

Even if you took a `const Numeric &n` instead, that won't help. The compiler doesn't know what type it used to be. And you can't even use `dynamic_cast` to convert it back, since `Numeric` is not a polymorphic class.

A better way to handle this is to actually use a proper `variant` class (`optional` is effectively a specialized `variant`).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out slicing, I hadn't heard of it before. I tried passing by value/reference, but neither worked. It's also helpful to know that sum types are called `variant`s in C++

Answer (score 1):

> My question is whether it's possible to move the `to_int` method outside of the classes, into the form of an overloaded function.

Using overloaded non-member functions is a viable option only if you deal with the derived types at all times.

If you need the functionality through a reference or pointer to the base class type, then using overloaded non-member functions is not a viable option. In that case, a `virtual` member function is the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a template class and an using declaration to do that:

```
template<int v>
struct Numeric {};

using NotANumber = Numeric<-1>;

template<int N>
constexpr int Numeric_to_int (Numeric<N>) {
    return N;
}

int main() {
    static_assert(Numeric_to_int(NotANumber{}) == -1, "!");
    static_assert(Numeric_to_int(Numeric<42>{}) == 42, "!");
}
```

Also, consider the use of a `std::integral_constant` for the same purpose.
As an example:

```
template<int v>
using Numeric = std::integral_constant<int, v>;
```

Comment: This is cool, but I think it requires me to know at compile time what my number is?

Comment: @user357269 From the example, I guessed they were known. Otherwise saying that you can use your function as `calculate_stuff(Number(4));` wouldn't have sense.

Comment: can you explain why that wouldn't make sense? I know at compile time whether it's a number (positive integer) or not a number.

Comment: @user357269 I mean, if you write - _I can use it as `Numeric{4}`_, one can think that you know at compile time your constants. It's not a minimal, working example that resembles the real problem. That's all. Not a problem, don't worry, just to be clearer in your questions in the future.